# Correct way to split csv file to remove extra " VB.net

Tags: vb.net, csv, datatable, split

I am importing a csv file into a datatable in a vb.net form application. When I import the csv file my code is adding an extra set of " around my dates. This is causing an error where my input array has more values than columns on my datatable. How do I remove the extra " with the split statement or another way.

Original line from csv file

```
 10411392601,Josue Smolcic 32278,10411392601,ProJet 7000,Not Burned-In,0.0,,0,,  ,10411392601 was started on 2019-10-02 11:41:13. 
 This Machine is Pending and still requires a passing inspection in Assembly / Integration. See Inspection Record #12367.,1.0,,This Machine is Pending and still requires a passing inspection in Assembly / Integration.
 ,"Oct 02, 2019","Oct 02, 2019 11:42 AM","Oct 02, 2019 11:41 AM",Pending, (2019-10-02 11:42:11)
```

After my code runs when I add a watch to the finalline variable I get this.

```
 "10411392601,Josue Smolcic 32278,10411392601,ProJet 7000,Not Burned- 
 In,0.0,,0,,  ,10411392601 was started on 2019-10-02 11:41:13. This Machine is Pending and still requires a passing inspection in Assembly / Integration. See Inspection Record #12367.,1.0,,This Machine is Pending and still requires a passing inspection in Assembly / Integration.
,""Oct 02, 2019"",""Oct 02, 2019 11:42 AM"",""Oct 02, 2019 11:41 AM"",Pending, (2019-10-02 11:42:11)"
```

Looking at the bottom line of both the examples you can see around the Oct dates there is an extra set of parentheses. How do I remove these?

Here is my vb code.

```
Private Sub MergetblAllMachines()
Dim path As String = "Pathway.csv"

    Dim f As Integer = 0
    Dim myreader As New StreamReader(path)
    Dim fullfilestr As String = myreader.ReadToEnd
    myreader.Close()
    myreader.Dispose()
    Dim lines As String() = fullfilestr.Split(ControlChars.Lf)
    Dim recs As New DataTable()
    Dim sarr As String() = lines(0).Split(","c)
    For Each s As String In sarr
        f = f + 1
        recs.Columns.Add(New DataColumn())
        ' MsgBox(s)
    Next
    Dim row As DataRow
    Dim finalline As String = " "
    For Each line As String In lines
        row = recs.NewRow()
        finalline = line.Replace(Convert.ToString(ControlChars.Cr), "")
        row.ItemArray = finalline.Split(","c)
        recs.Rows.Add(row) '-----Here is where my code bugs out------
    Next
end sub
```

### -

### -

### -

-----------------------Updated (Correct code)-----------------

attempting to use the textfieldparser class I have removed the double quotes but now I am having a hard time getting the strings split correctly. Here is my updated code.

```
        Dim path As String = "path.csv"

    Dim f As Integer = 0
    Dim myreader As New StreamReader(path)
    Dim fullfilestr As String = myreader.ReadToEnd
    myreader.Close()
    myreader.Dispose()
    Dim lines As String() = fullfilestr.Split(ControlChars.Lf)
    Dim recs As New DataTable()
    Dim sarr As String() = lines(0).Split(","c)
    For Each s As String In sarr
        f = f + 1
        recs.Columns.Add(New DataColumn())
        ' MsgBox(s)
    Next

        Dim SplitRow As String = Nothing
    Using myreader1 As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("path.csv")
        myreader1.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        myreader1.Delimiters = New String() {","}
        Dim currentrow As String()
        While Not myreader1.EndOfData
            Try
                currentrow = myreader1.ReadFields()

                recs.Rows.Add(currentrow)
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End While
    End Using
```

After running this all of each row is in the first cell of each row in the datatable. I need to split on the commas and then fill in the rest of each row. A side note, Recs is the datatable i am attempting to put everything into.

Comment: check out the TextFieldParser https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Jeremy alright im working on this solution, Ive got it mostly I just need to figure out how to split the string properly because each row is showing up as a string in the first cell of each row. This seems to have alleviated the double quotes issue.

Comment: is tab the correct delimiter?

Comment: @Jeremy No it was a comma, sorry that was a silly error on my part. It is working correctly now. If you want to answer this question with something I will mark it as the correct answer so you can get points for helping me out. Thanks again.